# Animating v-expansion-panel-content elements on v-expansion-panels change event in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to fire an v-expand-x-transition on the elements inside an v-expansion-panel-content when the expansion panel is opened or closed. I have this code:

```js
//The vue component
export default {
  data() {
    panels: [],
    expanded: [false, false, false] // ....
  },
  methods:{
    showBars() {
      this.expanded.forEach((element, index) => {
        this.expanded[index] = this.panels.indexOf(index) !== -1;
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<v-expansion-panels @change="showBars">
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <v-epand-x-transition :v-show="expanded[0]">
        <v-card/>
      </v-epand-x-transition>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
  
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <v-epand-x-transition :v-show="expanded[1]">
        <v-card/>
      </v-epand-x-transition>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
  <!-- ... other expansion panels -->
</v-expansion-panels>
```

With this aproach, when I close the expansion panel, the v-card shrinks as expected,but when I open the panel, it shrinks and then expands. Is like the v-show value is computed as true once the panel is closed.

How can I fire the v-expand-x-transition the right way, to expand the v-card when a panel is opened, and shrink it when the panel is closed?